# Tomcat can't see my Spring app when I run it

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am trying to build a simple Restful service with Spring but without Spring Boot.
I made config classes and then I tried to test controller but it is never triggered by request.
I tried java servlets - everthing worked fine.
So maybe the problem is within my config or dependencies.. Cant handle it myself
I am building project with Intellij

config classes:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[0];
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages ="ru.spring.testRest")
public class SpringConfig   {
    
}
```

controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class TestRest {

    @GetMapping("/here")
    public String test(){
        System.out.println("TRIGGERED");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Depndencies
[image: depndencies]

Tomcat
[image: Tomcat]

Comment: Spring boot 6 is for Tomcat 10. It uses JakartaEE not JavaEE. Remove the `javax.servlet-api` dependency and use the jakarta one (scope should be provided) and use the proper tomcat. Even better use Spring Boot instead of plain spring it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I switched to tomcat 10 and it finally worked. Thanks